# Unresolved compilation error when using external resources

Tags: actionlistener, eventhandler, actionevent

I'm getting an unresolved compilation error. Getting these errors:

> The method addActionListener(ActionListener) in the type
>   AbstractButton is not applicable for the arguments (Gui.HandlerClass)
>   The method addActionListener(ActionListener) in the type
>   AbstractButton is not applicable for the arguments (Gui.HandlerClass)
>   ActionListener cannot be resolved to a type ActionEvent cannot be
>   resolved to a type

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Gui extends JFrame{

private JButton reg;
private JButton custom;

public Gui(){
    super("The title");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    reg = new JButton("Regular Button");
    add(reg);

    Icon b = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("foto 1.png"));
    Icon c = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("foto 2.png"));
    custom = new JButton("Custom", b);
    custom.setRolloverIcon(c);
    add(custom);

    HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();
    reg.addActionListener(handler);
    custom.addActionListener(handler);
}

private class HandlerClass implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.format("%s", event.getActionCommand()));
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using * in imports. Your problem here is that `ActionListener` and `ActionEvent` classes are not imported. Therefore, you must import them:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
```

Also, what IDE are you using? Most IDEs would spot the problem and recommend you something in order to be fixed.